# In unity if spritemap is rectangular or square,does it have an impact on performance

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm using a flash tools in unity it supported two spritemap modes

Now i have two spritemap

one is 128x128

one is 123x156

I heard using squares can reduce drawcall, is it real？

If it doesn't really affect the drawcall, I'll use the following one

Answer (score 0):

In short - no, it doesn't. Or at least I didn't hear about such a thing.

However, there are several situations where using square textures with a side of power of 2 can fit better. But it is not a common case nowadays. And even then it will not affect drawcalls, only memory taken.

It can be useful in case you do not pack your textures into an atlas. Usually, all your images will pack into a single atlas with a side of power of 2 (like 1024x1024 or 2048x2048), so it is not important.